# Cannot find symbol import com.facebook.CallbackManager

Tags: facebook, react-native

Currently working on a react app which uses the `Facebook SDK`. It seems to brake on the import of `com.facebook.CallbackManager` with the following error:

```
/android/app/src/main/java/com/phonebook/theredcorner/MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
```

I've tried many suggestions online but it all doesn't seem to work. Anyone recently got this error and knows how to solve it?

I'm importing it in my `MainApplication.java` as follows

```
package com.phonebook.theredcorner;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
```

Furthermore I've followed all steps on the Facebook getting started page to implement the `Facebook SDK`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Facebook SDK was published as an independent module to `Maven`. Include the dependency in the `app/build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    // Facebook Core only (Analytics)
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:5.0.0'
}
```

You may also need to add the following to your `project/build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

If the error persists after installation, make sure the file is in the next path.

> facebook-android-sdk/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/CallbackManager.java